Color movie from east Asia, 1990-2007: a girl can see how long people have left to live
I need help identifying the movie I saw many years ago.

Color movie
~ 1990-2007
presumably Korean/Japanese (not necessarily)
genre - Mystery?.**

The gist of it is: a girl can see how long people have left to live. I remember only one scene: the girl walks down a street and looks at people passing by, there are numbers above their heads showing in how much time they will die. I don't remember it clearly but the next moment she sees a guy who's got about a minute on his clock (it might've looked something like this - 00.00.01.30) and he gets run over by a car. I just remembered, she probably could see ghosts aswell after they died, but I'm not sure.
I believe the movie is Korean/Japanese althought I'm not sure. I saw it about 10 years ago when I was a kid. It looks like a 2000s movie from what I remember (might be from 90s).

Not these: "In Time", "White Noise", very similar by concept to "Numbers", a book by Rachel Ward.
I photoshopped a quick mockup of how I remember it (tone, feel, setting...):


Sorry for vagueness, thanks in advance.

Was it feature length or short? (this one is a short).

Related question on SFF: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7164/movie-show-with-people-with-life-countdowns-on-their-foreheads

Thanks, that's very helpful. I don't think it's one on these but I might be remembering it wrong. I'll let you know as soon as I find it. I could not've thought so many movies/shows/videos used this idea. (Don't know its length as I only saw a few minutes of it but the one you posted is definitely too recent.)

Did you check out the short? One of the reasons I thought it matched well was because it's all set in Asia... though the main character doesn't see time of death, the film mentions another person who can see that.

It's definitely too recent (2012) to be the one I'm looking for. Oh, and that scene I described took place at daytime. Thanks btw, it's nice when random-internet-stranger-folks try to help.

The title rand Death Note, but it's not live action (unless I'm not aware of something)

@Gallifreyan The title rand?

@Gallifreyan Give it a few months.

@randal'thor s/d/g
